# Wrong Data on Fetch

Tags: php, mysql

I'm extracting data from a database but getting mixed returns. What I need is `bex_ref` of all entries where the `bex_ref` have a value and is between two dates.

Using two statements I'm getting the correct results. But combining it, it's returning data where the `bex_ref` is empty.

Combined (not working>

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `bex_ref` FROM `deliveries` WHERE `bex_ref`<>'' AND `inv_date` BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-07-13'  LIMIT 50 ")
```

First (working)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `bex_ref` FROM `deliveries` WHERE `bex_ref`<>'' LIMIT 50 ")
```

Second (working)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `bex_ref` FROM `deliveries` WHERE  `inv_date` BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-07-13'  LIMIT 50 ")
```

I'm expecting all results should have a `bex_ref` value but getting returns where `bex_ref` is empty but in the correct date range.

Comment: Please explain how you know that `bex_ref` is in the correct date range when it is empty. But, as you assume, the combined query seems correct to me. Do you have any rows in the database table where `bex_ref` is empty? That must be the case for the query to return `bex_ref` as empty. This could be a case where you're not actually telling us what happens. Either the query could have failed, or not returned any results.

Comment: using the combined statement I'm getting results between the date range but not all of the `bex_ref` fields have values in them. Yes there are entries where `bex_ref` are empty. Statement first and Second is what I used to try and find out what is wrong but cant. Using the First statement all the `bex_ref` fields have values in them. using the second statement all the returns are correct between the date range. It's almost (if not) when doing the Combined statement it's ignoring the `bex_ref`<>''

Comment: check all query it works fine. demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svGMffct6rEStwtX5ho1DL/10  might be somthing wrong with your php code .show php code how you execute the query

Answer (score 0):

Okay so something was very weird in my database. I noticed that while running the queries, that I actually can use.

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `bex_ref` FROM `deliveries` WHERE `bex_ref`<>'' AND `inv_date` BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-07-13'  LIMIT 50 ")
```

But when I want to echo my `bef_ref` values, my code is not executing. Running it in phpmyadmin I got the returns with empty values(Thus the confusion).

I then did a cleanup of my returns with mysqli_real_escape_string() and there it was invisible 0 in the "empty" values (returned /0 after the real_escape). I changed my Collation in the database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_ci and all was good.

They did a database restore on my db two days ago and that must have changed by db back to default latin1_swedish_ci.

Thank you for the replies!!